# Getting ClassNotFoundException when using Hibernate 3.6.3 and just added DefaultPreUpdateEventListener inside Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, exception, classloader

I have a problem that has been using Hibernate 3.6.0 for a very long time (or versions around here). This project has been in development since 2009 and has slowly but surely upgraded Hibernate versions. It's been using 3.6.x for some time.

I tried upgrading to 3.6.3 to see if it fixed the problem - it didn't. My tests still run.

I just recently created an implementation for DefaultPreUpdateEventListener. It works great when I unit test it in IntelliJ. It works when I run the tests in Maven. However, when I run my application in Tomcat, I get this stupid classpath error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [trainingdividend.dao.UpdatedOnEventListener] for bean with name 'trainingdividend.dao.UpdatedOnEventListener#1342f5b' defined in file [C:\Users\egervari\IdeaProjects\trainingdividend-experiment\target\classes\applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/event/def/DefaultPreUpdateEventListener
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:433)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/event/def/DefaultPreUpdateEventListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1483)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1242)
    ... 120 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPreUpdateEventListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
    ... 136 more
```

This doesn't really make sense. I have had no problems at all running Hibernate up to this point. None. Why is it that all of a sudden I am getting jar hell problems now for? I mean, this works in the unit/integration tests!

I really hate these kinds of problems. I'd appreciate it if someone could help. I've spent 2 hours trying to find out what is up, but I see no problem. My maven dependencies look good - it is only loading 1 version of Hibernate.

At times like this, I wish I was using Rails. I doubt they ever put up with this crap.

Here's my spring configuration of Hibernate:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="pre-update">
                <bean class="trainingdividend.dao.UpdatedOnEventListener" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>hibernate/coursetemplate.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/address.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/user.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/trainee.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/company.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/instructor.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/module.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/sysadmin.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="namingStrategy">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the jars are included in the class path. try putting jars in tomcat lib.

if u r using custom listeners have u tried adding the event listeners explicitly in the configuration?

```
<event type="load">
            <listener class="com.eg.MyLoadListener"/>
            <listener class="org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener"/>
</event>
```

or u can implement *org.hibernate.event.PreUpdateEventListener*

Comment: That was the first thing I looked at. I have checked my maven dependencies. The correct jars are in fact there. I mean, I've been running Hibernate FOREVER. It's been there for a very long time. It's still there. It didn't disappear. I think this is one of those errors that has nothing to do with what it is actually saying.

Comment: any new custom listeners added?

Comment: I'm adding the event listener in Spring. I am not using JPA - just regular hibernate

Comment: try adding another entry for org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPreUpdateEventListener to listener class

Comment: in 3.6.3 there is no org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPreUpdateEventListener

Comment: That still gives the same error. My specific event listener inherits from org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPreUpdateEventListener. It exists in IntelliJ and Maven... so I have to assume it should exist in Tomcat... but it doesn't :(

Comment: @hGx: really? The why does intellij and maven have it then... GRRRRR. I wonder what the Hibernate people renamed it to...

Comment: so instead of extending DefaultPreUpdateEventListener, implement org.hibernate.event.PreUpdateEventListener

Comment: Yay, it worked! Thank you! I have no idea why Maven's classpath would know what this class was when Maven was only loading the 3.6.x jar... it should have failed just like it does in tomcat. There is definitely some bug going on. How this came out to be doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the source of hibernate 3.6.3, you'll see that class doesn't exist.
Hence I suspect if you recompile your trainingdividend.dao.UpdatedOnEventListener with it's classpath pointin to hibernate 3.6.3, you'll see that doesn't work (To be honest I checked Hibernate 3.3.2 as well, and it aint there either)

You'll need to implement your own case of the interface PreUpdateEventListener  - which does exist.

Comment: Even after a 'maven clean', Maven found this class when I ran all of my tests even though this class wasn't supposed to exist for me. This is what tripped me up. I use the exact same pom.xml to start tomcat... yet it didn't work. Sure, if I got this error in my IDE and when I ran the tests in Maven, I would have solved it in 3 seconds. But it WORKED. This led me to believe it was some BS error and not what it said it was. In fact, I still don't know why Maven runs the tests. I have no clue. It shouldn't have ran them at all - it should have failed.